# Delete local windows profile with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, wmi

I am trying to write a script that will delete the local profile of a test account. I am using the following line to return the SID of any account that starts with "test-"

PowerShell: `$UserSID = (Get-WmiObject Win32_UserProfile | Where {$_.LocalPath -like '*\test-*'}).SID`

Once I had the SID I used wmic to do the deletion but, I am not sure how to translate that code into PowerShell.

WMIC:`wmic /node:"localhost" path win32_UserProfile where Sid="%%b" Delete`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was thinking this would work, but I don't find a delete method on the Win32_UserProfile class

```
$UserSID = (Get-WmiObject Win32_UserProfile | Where {$_.LocalPath -like '*\test-*'}).SID
(gwmi -class Win32_UserProfile -filter "SID='$UserSID'").Delete()
```

Comment: I get the following error:
Exception calling "Delete" with "0" argument(s): ""
At line:2 char:64
+ (gwmi -class Win32_UserProfile -filter "SID='$UserSID'").Delete <<<< ()
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException

Comment: I needed to add "-ComputerName localhost" to your line.

Comment: To resolve the error " Exception calling "Delete" with "0" argument(s):" run Powershell as administrator.

Answer (score 3):

You can also just call the Delete method directly in a single statement:

```
(Get-WmiObject Win32_UserProfile | Where {$_.LocalPath -like '*\test-*'}).Delete()
```

Answer (score 2):

Another reason of getting ***Exception calling "Delete" with "0" argument(s)*** is the user you're trying to delete is currently logged in. Log him off and try again.

Comment: run Powershell as administrator resolved that error for me.

Comment: Rather, run `([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal] [Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole] "Administrator")` and see if it returns True, indicating you are Administrator.

Answer (score 1):

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_UserProfile -Filter "RoamingConfigured = 'True'" | Remove-WmiObject
```

`True` - Roaming profile
`False` - Local Profile

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this issue by opening Powershell as administrator (right click, Run as Administrator).