# Suggestions for setting up a kiosk mode in Windows 7

Tags: windows, profile

I'm exploring a simple way to create a kiosk mode for Windows 7. I work at a property management company that managements apartment homes. Each property has a business center with PC's available for resident use. Right now we're paying for software to severely lock down the PC's so resident can't trash them, which they do every chance they get. I'm looking for a much simpler and cost-effective solution.

My thought is to restrict the "resident" account to User priviledges and delete that user profile at every startup. They won't be able to install apps or save anything to the PC permanently that way.

I'm having trouble with the delete the profile. Most tools to delete profiles focus on deleting profile older than a set timeframe. Those won't work because I can't set them for less than 24 hours. I tried a simple "rd C:\Users\Resident /s /q" in a scheduled task, but that fails to run prior to logon under SYSTEM or an admin acct's credentials. These are basic PC's without powershell 3 installed, so most powershell scripts are out.

It just needs to be a simple destruction of the profile. Quick and dirty and let Windows build a new one at each reboot. Any thoughts or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: SteadyState and Guest Mode are out now. Microsoft cancelled those and basically said, "Tough luck. Here's a word doc to kind of replicate what it was." linky: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=24373. I've used Deep Freeze and Cleanslate. I want to get away from license fees and just delete the profile. I think that will do it if I can pin down a process that works pre-logon.

Comment: I can add a batch file to the shutdown scripts list in GP. That will allow me to delete the folder and registry entires from the ProfileList key. It's the perfect clean wipe. BUT the SID is different for each PC. I'm not aware of a way to search for a portion of a key and delete what it finds. Every user profile key starts with S-1-5-21. If I could run a search and delete each key that start with those figures, I'd be golden. :(

Comment: Can't you do `net user resident /delete` and `net user resident /add` command from scheduled tasks at windows startup/shutdown? won't that work? I'm setting up a Windows 7 VM right know, I will try some stuff myself.

Comment: Also, do the residents have physicall access to the USB ports or something? If not use a virtual machine and lock the keyboard in the virtual machine.Set the virtual machine to non-persisent so it will restore itself at each reboot of the VM, yet giving the guests full control of the temporary VM OS

Comment: I also found these links which may be usefull: [1](http://teamtutorials.com/windows-tutorials/configuring-your-own-kiosk-machine) [2](http://helpdeskgeek.com/how-to/how-to-setup-windows-vista-and-7-as-a-kiosk/) [3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_Freeze_%28software%29)

Comment: If you have Microsoft "software assurance" - you could use Windows Thin PC with enhanced write filter. That's essentially a slimmed down version of windows, with a 'steadystate' / 'deepfreeze' functionality. Guessing based on your requirements, you don't have software assurance.

Comment: Jason: No, no software assurance. I'm going to have to do this the homegrown, old-fashioned way. Gam: The resident do have access to the USB port. These properties have a Business Center with multiple PC's and a printer, similar to what you'd find in a hotel. I need to maintain the ability to connect a thumb drive or phone and pull docs. I'm fine giving them User access, I just want to erase their mess on each reboot.

Comment: I didn't think about `net user resident /delete or /add`. I did write a small shutdown script to GP. The script simply uses `RD C:\Users\Residents /S /Q` and `REG DELETE` to delete all S-1-5-21 entries in the Registry ProfileList key. I think that will do it, but I'm still testing. If deleting the account will also delete the User folder, then that should take care of it entirely. I'll report back in a bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found my answer.

I added a shutdown batch script to machine group policy that does the following...

```
NET USER Resident /DELETE
RD C:\Users\Resident\ /S /Q
NET USER Resident /ADD
NET USER /COMMENT:"Resident"
NET USER /FULLNAME:"Resident"
NET USER /PASSWORDCHG:NO
NET USER /EXPIRES:NEVER
WMIC PATH Win32_UserAccount WHERE NAME='Resident' SET PasswordExpires=FALSE
REG DELETE "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\S-1-5-21" /f
```

This removes and readds the account, deletes the folder and associated registry entries. I have an admin account that won't be adversely affected by the key removal at all. This accomplishes what I want. The account is restricted in the way I need, and it is refreshes at every reboot.

My last action was to create a task to reboot the PC nightly.

```
SCHTASKS /CREATE /TN "NightlyReboot" /TR "SHUTDOWN -R -F -T 0" /SC DAILY /ST 03:00:00 /SD 01/01/2013
```

That'll 'bout do it. :)

Thank you everyone for your help and suggestions. I was able to take a little something from everything and make a sound solution. And now I've saved us $6-7k in yearly licenses fees. WOOHOO!!

Comment: I found the solution presented here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3755741/delete-local-windows-profile-with-powershell to be even easier, one line of code and I don't get issues with PowerShell (I opted for that rather than a batch file).